# changing an element's background using the CSS property

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, background-position

I have a div with a background, and I'd like to change the background's position on click.

This is my jQuery snippet :

```
$('#sprite').click(function () {
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '-40px');
});
```

While this is working ok, I'd like to return to the original position with a 'second' click, resetting all.

Mmm, is this what's called a 'callback' right?

I tried so with that but it didn't work :

```
$('#sprite').click(function () {
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '-40px');
},function () {
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '40px');
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should consider using a "toggle" function for this...  It'll allow you to go between 2 different CSS classes...  Check out this tutorial [here](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/easy-toggle-jquery-tutorial/).

```
$('#sprite').click(function() {
   $(this).toggle(
      function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '40px');
      }, 
      function () {
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '-40px');
    });
});
```

Another option rather than setting the CSS property directly would be to create a CSS class for your background and simply toggle that class.

### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .spritebg { background-position: -40px; }
</style>
```

### jQuery

```
$("#spite").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("spritebg");
});
```

Comment: Yeah, speedy! Btw, you can just use toggle by itself, no need for the click too: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/toggle

Answer (score 3):

Do it with classes. It's much much easier.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #spite.moved {
        background-position: -40px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#spite").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("moved");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're mis-understanding the concept of a callback. A callback in programming is a function that gets called immediately after the executing code.

In your case, you're saying the following:

On click, set my background position to -40px. Once you're done with that, set it to 40px (immediately undoing what your function just did).

In this case, you don't need to use a callback function. You need to set up a toggle so that when the user clicks on your element, one function is run...then the next time they click on that element, the second function is run.